# Passing VARS to another console on Fedora

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

I'm trying to source the config.sh file from a path that's defined in a variable.  How do I get my variable to expand in the current console.  Here are my commands:

```
[root@mysystem]#export AUTO_PATH="/mnt/share/__automation__"         
[root@mysystem]#runuser -l $(who | grep tty2 | awk -F " " '{print $1}') -c 'source $AUTO_PATH/config.sh;gnome-screensaver-command -d;xset dpms force on'
```

These are the outputs that I get:

```
-bash: /config.sh: No such file or directory
** Message: Failed to get session bus: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=cb264e3a020119540fab776c00000007 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
xset:  unable to open display ""
```

I'm running on Fedora 16 and I'm trying to turn off the screensaver off before I do a screencapture.  My `$DISPLAY` value is stored in my config.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your single quotes to double quotes:

This:

```
-c 'source $AUTO_PATH/config.sh;gnome-screensaver-command -d;xset dpms force on'
```

Should be like this:

```
-c "source $AUTO_PATH/config.sh;gnome-screensaver-command -d;xset dpms force on"
```

From the `bash(1)` man page:

```
 Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the  literal  value  of
 each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur between
 single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

 Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the  literal  value  of
 all  characters  within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and,
 when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $  and  `  retain
 their  special meaning within double quotes.
```

This means that any `$` expression, such as a variable expansion, is still honored when it's in double quotes, but not if it's in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a whirl when I get to work on monday